# Current URL without parameters, hash, http(s)://

Tags: javascript, string, url

I'm looking for a neat way of getting the URL of the current document in Javascript.

- The URL should be clean of parameters (?parameter1=bla&parameter2=bla)
- The URL should be clean of hash tags (#jumppoint)
- http/https should be removed/consolidated into http

I know i can get the current URL with location.href and then use some regular expressions to clean it up but maybe there is a nicer/cleaner solution for getting rid of the junk?

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote just for calling important parts of the url "junk"!

Comment: @Douglas Importance is subjective. It's entirely plausible that in the context of this function only the host is the relevant part.

Comment: ptorocol can be ftp: as well, do you need to consider it?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are many other parameters than the `href` in `window.location`. See full reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

What you are looking for as a starter might be the `window.location.hostname`:

> "the host name (without the port number or square
>   brackets)."

From the example URL `http://[www.example.com]:80/search?q=devmo#test` the hostname will be `www.example.com`.

If you also want to include the path and force a http:// protocol, try:

```
'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;
```

As a side note, a nifty trick to get the same parameters from another URL than the window.location is to create an empty anchor:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://www.example.com:80/search?q=devmo#test';

console.log('http://' + a.hostname + a.pathname);
```

Comment: I think they want the pathname too.

Comment: @jfriend00 yea, the docs should be enough to figure things out, but I added that too for clarity.

Comment: `'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname;`
you forgot the port

Answer (score 35):

None of the given answers address the fact that the protocol can be http or https as in the OPs title. To accommodate this I suggest:

```
document.location.protocol +"//"+ document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname
```

Comment: If you have a port number in your URL, this solution causes the port number to be lost, ie http://localhost:49346/ becomes http://localhost.

Answer (score 5):

The [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Location_object) got what you need

```
window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `document.location` object, so:

```
var oLoc = document.location,
    sUrl = oLoc.protocol + oLoc.hostname;
    // or "http://" + oLoc.hostname
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use these replacement functions to remove the hash and search arguments and normalize https to http:

```
url = url.replace(/#[^#]*$/, "").replace(/\?[^\?]*$/, "").replace(/^https:/, "http:");
```

Or, if all you really want is the domain and path, you can just use this:

```
window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this snippet:

```js
if (!window.location.origin){
  // For IE
  window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');      
}

url = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
document.write('Origin url: ' + url);
```

Comment: This was already answered long ago. And this answer is wrong regarding the question as it will still provide https:// as the origin protocol if the page is https - but it should strip the protocol/readd it as http.

Comment: Isn't there the host name missing in the for-IE code? Like
`window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '')
                + '/' + window.location.hostname;`

Comment: yes, but not in that order : window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port ? ':' + window.location.port : '');

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ecmascript/quickref/location.html) page indicates that you could probably use `window.location.host` to get the part you're actually interested in. I haven't tested it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
window.location.hostname;
```