# How to get current url without page in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

How can I get current URL without page in Javascript or jQuery.

For example, if the url is:

http://www.abc.com/music/pop.aspx

I want to get the full path without the page so like:

http://www.abc.com/music/

No need to worry about parameters.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513736/current-url-without-parameters-hash-https

Comment: window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname

Comment: @NickN. That post is about removing parameters. The answer still has the page name which I wish to remove. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to extract the desired part of url.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JdSuU/)**

```
urlBase = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

You can use window.location.href to get the current url

```
urlBase = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
```

Comment: +1 and it's better to write like this: `url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);`

Comment: Thanks @Siamak.A.M, so nice of you.

Answer (score 4):

Use `window.location` and `substring`.

```
location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

Comment: This answer will be wrong if parameter contains `"/"`: `test.com/path/?para=this/bad`

Answer (score 4):

These answers are all good. For the sake of others who come by here later and want an entirely encapsulated answer I thought I'd pull together a function

```
function locationHREFWithoutResource() { 
    var pathWORes   = location.pathname.substring(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    var protoWDom   = location.href.substr(0, location.href.indexOf("/", 8));
    return protoWDom + pathWORes;
};
```

This will return the entire URL (href) up to the last directory including a trailing slash. I tested it across a bunch of different URLs by visiting sites and dropping the function in the console then calling it. Some example and results:

```
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
    -> "http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/"

https://www.google.com/
    -> "https://www.google.com/"`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417791/how-to-get-current-url-without-page-in-javascript-or-jquery
    -> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417791/"
```

That last one is this page.