# Work out the baseUrl of a page

Tags: javascript, node.js

Imagine I have:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com:10/one/two/three.html";
```

This is the URL of a page I just fetched.

I want to baseUrl: `http://www.example.com:10/one/two/`.
The most obvious way is to use a regexp to take out the last part of the URL. However, it feels a little unsafe and hacky. Is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current url without page in javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417791/how-to-get-current-url-without-page-in-javascript-or-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)` should do the job !

Comment: This is nice... better than `u.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/')` (what I had come up with!)

Comment: I had to wait the minimum 5 minutes before accepting it :D

Comment: Oh, sorry, was not aware of that !