# Get path including GET variables using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need to get the whole path of page (excluding the domain) so I can show it in an iframe.

I currently use `location.pathname` to get the path, but the problem is that they may appear `GET` variables in the URL.

So for a page like `article.php?id=23` I get only `article.php` using `location.pathname`,  thus the page displayed in the `iframe` is simply a 404 page.

Is there any function to get the path including GET variables?

Comment: Question already been answer!?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406192/how-to-get-the-current-url-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: I don't see any answer that may help, can you link to that one?

Comment: look at the bottom right of this page :)

Comment: Well, no answer is helpful, I only need the path including `GET` variables, so hashes for example should be ignored.

Comment: Ok. Do another finding! :) Information is out there! You'll probably need some substring to select the part before the hash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513736/current-url-without-parameters-hash-https

Comment: My question is if `Is there any function to ...` to get what I want directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There probably isn't an out of the box function, no.

But you can use this as a reference to create your own:

[Mozilla DOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.location)

Specifically, using `window.location.pathname` (strip the leading "/" if you don't want it) and `window.location.search` to get the querystring.

i.e

```
function whatIWant()
{
    return  window.location.pathname.substring(1) + window.location.search;
}
```

Comment: `location.search` is exactly what I need. I'll use `window.location.pathname + window.location.search` thanks :).

Comment: glad you got it sorted.

Comment: If you're coming here in 2022+ try checking out this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/5070253)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.search.replace( "?", "" );
```

this will return the get variables.

LINK=http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/location.shtml

*Answer to your question*->no,there is **no** any built in function ,we have to make our custom function and parse it.

[Get escaped URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403888/get-url-parameter-with-jquery)

Comment: And, what function from `window.location` can I use to get `article.php?id=23` from `www.domain.com/article.php?id=23#hash` ?

Comment: You could use a regex expression if the URL stays consistent