# How to get only the Controller name and action name from URL with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am using .net MVC in my website and I need to get the URL in javascript, but only the controller and action name, for instance if i have:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513736/current-url-without-parameters-hash-https`

I need:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513736/`

I have found some solutions such as:

`urlBase = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1)`

`->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513736/`

However if my URL does not have any parameters I the action name is cut off like so:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/`

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Depends how consistent and reliable the URL will be. You could check to see if the URL ends with `/` if it does then don't substring it. That might work for you. Personally I would look to see if you can access the controller and action names through razor and write it directly to the javascript so you don't have to parse it.

Comment: URLS don't work like that; you only get the path. What happens after that is completely in your hands.

Comment: This is impossible without also duplicating all the route logic in JS.
Instead, you probably want to have the server echo this data back via the payload for you to consume on the client.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use 
`window.location.pathname` 
for this.

For the url in this question it returns

```
"/questions/28946447/how-to-get-only-the-controller-name-and-action-name-from-url-with-jquery"
```

To read it properly you can use: `window.location.pathname.split("/")`
Read the value with:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var questions = url[1];
```

Comment: thanks, this is my final solution: 

`var manJSCmon = location.pathname.split("/");`
`var local = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + "/" + manJSCmon[1] + "/" + manJSCmon[2];`

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.pathname;
```

this will return `path` from the url . then use `split` to get controller name and action name

```
var path=window.location.pathname;
var abc=path.split("/");
var controller=abc[0];
var action=abc[1] || "index";
```